# insert & update users in oracle internet directory (OID) in .net

Tags: .net, active-directory, ldap, oid

I have very little experience in working with OID and for starters i managed to connect to OID  and find users in OID from .net with help from the forums. I am still struggling to get the Insert and Update to OID from .Net. Does any one have an idea/ example which i can work on.

Your help is highly appreciated!!!!
Thanks in Advance
Rama

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this: [Introduction to System.DirectoryServices.Protocols (S.DS.P)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332056.aspx)

If so, you need to be a bit more specific about what the problem is.